# Instance Declarations

Tags: haskell

Bit curious why the instance declaration is needed in the following as a default implementation is provided.

```
module Example where

class Eq a => EQ a where
    eq :: a -> a -> Bool
    eq = (==)

-- why is this instance declaration needed?
instance EQ Int where
    eq = (==)

f :: Int -> Int -> Bool
f = eq
```

If I leave out the instance declaration I get an error. I'm sure it's explained somewhere in the Haskell report but it will take a while to find it.

Comment: Because a `class` instance does not construct an `instance` automagically.

Comment: Thanks to @WillemVanOnsem. I should have realised there's no need to write a `where` clause for the `instance` declaration. Just writing `instance EQ Int` is enough and equipes `Int` with the default implementation of `eq`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're definition of a class, is probably more what in Java/C#/... is a `class`.

If you write:

```
class Eq a => EQ a where
    eq :: a -> a -> Bool
    eq = (==)
```

You only define a typeclass: a way to add functions to a type class and write restrictions. You have **not** written that every `Eq a` is an `EQ a`... You have written that in order to implement `EQ a`, you have to implement `Eq a` as well (which is a bit weird here).

Furthermore you have provided a *default* implementation: `eq = (==)`, but that is only a default implementation for an *instance* where you do not specify the implementation.

By writing:

```
instance EQ Int where
    eq = (==)
```

you have now defined that `Int` is an `EQ`. You can make the instance more useful by writing for instance:

```
instance Eq a => EQ a
```

Now you have written than *all* types `a` for which `Eq a` holds, also are a type instance of `EQ`. If you write that however, you have immediately defined the entire universum of `EQ` since in your `class` definition, you restricted `a` to be an instance of `EQ`, so that means that now, in the entire Haskell universe, `eq` is equal to `(==)`.

You probably want to say:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

class EQ a where
    eq :: a -> a -> Bool

instance Eq a => EQ a where
    eq = (==)
```

Now you defined a typeclass `EQ` and for every type `a` that is `Eq a`, we set `eq` to `(==)`, but it allows you to define an `EQ` over other types as well, like `data Foo` that is not an instance of `Eq`. Mind that we have to turn on two extensions here. These are compiler specific, and thus are not part of standard Haskell.

Comment: I don't think your last `instance` is allowed as the type does not involve a type constructor applied to simple type variables. Please see page 46 of the Haskell 2010 report. It would be allowed if it started with `instance Eq a => EQ [a]`, e.g.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: you are correct that Haskell 2010 does not allow it. But ghc allows it. GHC is a superset of Haskell.

Comment: Thanks. Please make your answer reflect this and explain this. I'll accept the answer if you do.

Comment: Thanks for adding the ghc `LANGUAGE` pragmas to your last answer, which aren't proper Haskell (2010).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: yeah, I also added a note at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. The note doesn't make clear this is only ghc compatible. I also suggest you omit the "you probably want to say:" because I was looking for a Haskell solution, not  a Haskell dialect (ghc) solution.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: welll that we can not know. Everybody is free to construct his/her own compiler (some of my friends did) and they can include/exclude any feature. :)

Comment: I disagree. You write "you probably want to say" so how do you know I wish to use ghc (which I do but it's irrelevant).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I mean that it is not GHC specific. It is not standard Haskell, but that does not mean that it is specific to a single compiler :). It is an N.B. and most part of my answers are irrelevant since these indeed not answer the problem itself, but look for ways of improvement :). It has usually a structure of problem statement - (solution) - remarks. Whether the remarks add value is of course uncertain. Otherwise we would not call this research.

Comment: All fine but why not improve your answer by making it easier for a novice who knows very little about Haskell by clearly pointing out which of your statements are true (Haskell) and which are ``not'' (dialects)? At the moment it is not clear...